# What is a "closing gown"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> There were fringed bolero jackets in abundance and multiple rose-bedecked references to the so-intense-as-to-hurt romantic aesthetic of Frida Kahlo. The **closing gown** was painted by Romero Britto as a tribute to the trailblazing Mexican artist. ([source](https://www.vogue.com/article/dolce-gabbana-alta-moda-mexico-city))

Google seems to show this is not a thing. But then what does "closing" mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closing gown is the last gown (dress) to be displayed in the fashion show. "Closing" as an adjective can be used about something that comes at or near the end of an event.

> adjective [ before noun ]
>
> coming near the end of a speech, event, activity, etc.:
>
> In his closing remarks, the chairman thanked everyone who had helped.
>
> the closing ceremony of the OIympic Games

[Closing (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/closing)

> closing
>   ADJECTIVE
>   attributive
>
> Bringing something to an end; final.
>
> ‘the closing stages of the election campaign’
>
> ‘Nellie's closing words’

[Closing (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/closing)